# Saying "you've caught me" or "you caught me" when surprised

Tags: tense

When someone surprises another person, which is the correct way for answering?

"You've caught me!" or "You caught me!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either is correct.

However, this is not usually what I say when I'm surprised. :-)

Comment: Can you please explain how `You've caught me` is correct, it sounds a bit awkward.

Comment: What I'm saying, would be like you was going to execute a prank, and the person which would take this prank, cut off you! Now you say, `Ohh you've caught me`

Comment: It doesn't actually. The **present perfect** tense shows a complete action which has a result in the present. So if I find someone and gives me such answer, my response could be anything.

Comment: @udhy: *You've got me there!* That's a standard way of expressing befuddlement / inability to respond, and *caught* can certainly replace *got* in such contexts (plus even native speakers won't always be sure which word was actually uttered, since they can sound very similar).